# e.force:navigateToURL throwing error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, forcenavigatetourl

Below is the javascript function in `AccountListcontroller.js` that fires on clicking a button on lightning component,but it is throwing error

`This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.Action failed: c:AccountList$controller$sendVF [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:AccountList$controller$sendVF}`

```
 sendVF: function (component, event, helper) {
   var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": 'www.google.com'
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

I am testing this in developer console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your inputs:

> 1. I am trying this is in Lightning Application
> 2. I am testing this in developer console.

You cannot actually test this by "previewing" from developer console.

If you look at `force:navigateToURL` event's [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation), it mentions:

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

This means that it will only work in applications in those context.

Furthermore, if you see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_application.htm) of a Lightning Application, it mentions:

> An app is a special top-level component whose markup is in a .app resource.

That means, if you preview your app from the developer console you will see in the URL something as `https://..../myapp.app`, which is not definitely in the context what the event expects.

Your best option here to test this out is to put this snippet in a Lightning Component instead and test it by adding it to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing the Component into the **Lightning Application OR VF page** **force:navigateToURL** does not directly work with the **stand-alone application**. This event works in Lightning Platform only. I am not sure but you can try PageReference for the same and see if this Works Below is the Link: 
[Lightning:navigation PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation)

Comment: I am trying this is in Lightning Application

Comment: Unfortunately force:navigateToURL does not work in Lightning Application. Give the page reference a try and see if this works.

Comment: Can I ask you for example use of PageReference for similar scenario

Comment: Sorry we can not use Page Reference to redirect to External URL. use location.href = 'https://www.google.com' to redirect to the URL.

Also, If you wanted to redirect between salesforce components, we can use PageReference. Plese refer the link for examples
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm